# Safari 12 not caching big assets in case of redirect 302, it works fine if added directly in the page?

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am using  **Safari Version 12.0.2 (13606.3.4.1.4)** and I have very simple page like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
  <script src="https://d161vkckch5xxj.cloudfront.net/LS/ASSETS/PROD/US/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Hello There
</body>
</html>
```

This shows when I reload the page the asset is loading from the cache which is expected.

[image: Safari Caching the Direct Links]

Changing the Script tag to a URL which redirects to this asset because there are different variations of this script and based on the context right script will be loaded. So when I change script tag from

```
  <script src="https://d161vkckch5xxj.cloudfront.net/LS/ASSETS/PROD/US/bundle.js"></script>
```

To this

```
<script src="https://pvpsx9qpxa.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/PROD/getAsset?marketplace=US&assetName=bundle.js"></script>
```

Which points to the same asset, now when I reload the page every time, the whole asset is getting loaded and it's not hitting the cache at all, Mobile Safari has the exact same issue.

[image]

In chrome and FF it works the right way and shows the redirect as well, what to do for Safari as it's a big asset and can't be freshly loaded every time.

Chrome results,

[image]
[image]

Comment: Speculation: it may not be specifically the fact that there's a redirect, but rather that there's a temporary redirect from a request that includes a query string. (I'm not saying that behavior would make any more sense... just speculating that this could be the specific trigger.)  Is there a reason you are using a 302 rather than a 301 (or 307)?

Comment: Nope, 301 also has the same behaviour I tested the same.